# How can I create a div/button with stacked text inside?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to figure out how to produce this in CSS:

[image]

However, when I've tried this thus far, it's only partially been on track:

[image]

How can I fix the below CSS and HTML so that it works as a stacked text meter properly? I do have Bootstrap, and I'm using SCSS/SASS.

A Pen with the same code, including the full menu, shows the same issue:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLYWZR

```css
.buFontSize {
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.pointButton {
    display: block;
    border: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.534) 1px solid !important;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0px !important;
}

.buttonBlock {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark">
  

  <div class="navbar" id="navbarText">
    <a class="navbar-brand navBrand" href="#">Link One</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link Two</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link Three</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  <ul class="navbar-nav float-right">
      <span class="btn pointButton">
        <div class="buttonBlock">
            <div class="row">
                <span class="buFontSize">Games</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <span class="buFontSize">100000</span>
            </div>
        </div>
      </span>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas faSize fa-user-friends"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="far faSize fa-envelope"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>      
</div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: why not just use a br? Also div inside span is invalid

Comment: The code you've provided (even after including Bootstrap) doesn't match the screenshot you've taken. Can you edit the code snippet above to more closely match the output in your screenshots?

Comment: Use br to breaklines, fix the positioning use display (flex or anything you like) and use padding to fix the position of the text inside the button

Comment: I added the full menu, and included a Pen link to show the problem as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a button group with a br:

```css
body {
  background-color: black !important; /* test only */
}

.btn-group .btn {
  background: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  line-height:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-group">
  <div class="btn">
    Games<br>
    10000
  </div >
  <div class="btn">
    Points<br>
    000000
  </div >
</div>
```

[Example bootply](https://www.bootply.com/vjdBqVzigw)

Comment: This did the trick, thanks. I've been trying to figure it out for the last day.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help - if you have a look at the bootply, it's quite handy as it has dropdown lists of ready made components you can use (just above the editable html)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.buFontSize {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0px;
}

.pointButton {
    display: block;
    border: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.534) 1px solid;
    background: #000;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0px;
}

.buttonBlock {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<span class="btn pointButton">
  <div class="buttonBlock">
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-12">
           <span class="buFontSize">Games</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
           <span class="buFontSize">100000</span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
}
.buttonBlock{
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 1px solid white;
 width: 120px;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}

.buttonBlock > span{
 display: block;
}

.buttonBlock:first-child{
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
 -ms-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
 -o-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.buttonBlock:last-child{
 border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
 -ms-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
 -o-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.buttonBlock:not(:first-child){
 border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="btn pointButton">
  <div class="buttonBlock">
   <span class="title">First</span>
   <span class="points">100000</span>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonBlock">
   <span class="title">Second</span>
   <span class="points">100000</span>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonBlock">
   <span class="title">Third</span>
   <span class="points">100000</span>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonBlock">
   <span class="title">Fourth</span>
   <span class="points">100000</span>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonBlock">
   <span class="title">Fifth</span>
   <span class="points">100000</span>
  </div>
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Use

```
.somewrapperclass{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap row;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Don't use display block as there is a better alternative, check this [complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)